# c++: is it safe to cast pointer to functions?

Tags: c++, assembly, casting, function-pointers

I'm wondering if it's safe to cast a `double (*)(double)` to `double(*)(...)`, this is going to be used to generalize a code which may have pointers to multiple functions.

so far I've stored every thing that is going to be passed to the function in a vector, and I'm wondering if there is a way to call a function (while passing the correct number of arguments) in a generalized code? I mean something this:

```
//while initializing
mFunction = sin;
//later in code
double (*generalized)(...) = mFunction;
for(i=0;i<args.size();i++)
    pusharg(args[i]);
call(generalized);
```

**--edit--**

if there is not a valid way to do it using c++ is it possible to saftly call the function using assembly?

Comment: well, it's  not! I'm trying to cast from a "pointer to function" to "pointer to function with some other signiture", while he trying to cast "void*" to a "function pointer"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly assign a `double(*)(double)` to `double(*)(...)`, but you could `reinterpret_cast` it. The cast is explicitly allowed by §5.2.10[expr.reinterpret.cast]/6, but calling the casted function pointer will cause undefined behavior:

> A function pointer **can** be explicitly converted to a function pointer of a different type.
>
> The effect of calling a function through a pointer to a function type that is not the same as the type used in the definition of the function is **undefined**.
>
> Except that converting a prvalue of type “pointer to `T1`” to the type “pointer to `T2`” (where `T1` and `T2` are function types) and back to its original type yields the **original** pointer value, the result of such a pointer conversion is unspecified.

It is easy to see why it leads to UB — what if we call `generalized(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)`? This will likely corrupt the call stack. But it is fine if you cast the `generalized` back to a `double(*)(double)` before you call it.

Comment: since it's a private member, I don't need worry about possible programmer mistakes. so if I've converted `sin(double)` to `generalize(double, ...)`, I will only call `generalize(1.0)` or if it's `hypot(double,double)` I can make sure to only call `generalize(1.0,2.0)`

Comment: @Gajet: It's still better to cast back to the original type if possible to avoid error. The `...` may change the calling convention (e.g. if you pass a `float` to a `...` argument, it will be converted to a `double` before calling the function.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the casting itself is allowed. To call it with a wrong signature is not, though. Note that if you want a generic function pointer, better use `void (*)()`, it's like `void*` for function pointers (no implicit conversion to it, though).

Or even better, since you apperently provide specific arguments, use `std::function` and `std::bind` (if your compiler supports C++11 libraries), or their Boost equivalents.

Comment: "_Note that if you want a generic function pointer, better use `void (*)()`_" I would rather use a pointer that cannot be called, like `void (*)(boost::noncopyable)`.

Comment: is there an equivalent assembly code that does the trick for me?

Comment: @Gajet: As I'm sure you know, assembly is highly unportable. It would be possible though. I implemented my own delegate class for fun with it, because the calling code becomes basically a few assembly lines. Note however, that it's very buggy and likely to cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Making `generalized` volatile will require the compiler to follow the ABI specification. Due to a desire to support non-declared C functions this is safe on most ABIs (including x86 and x86-32) if one does not call a function that excepts a variable number of arguments though a pointer to function with a fixed number of arguments.